# Не запускается exe файл через node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe, exec

Использую этот код для запуска exe файла (Эта программа НЕ подразумевает запуск с опеределённым каталогом. При обычном запуске, работает нормально.):

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec(`C:/upd/${rand}.exe`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Получаю ошибку:
"error: Command failed: C:/upd/yawuqxnsypqnalundwglxzawq.exe
я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ я┐╜ файя┐╜я┐╜, так я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ файя┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜угия┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜сом."
Как это исправить? Спасибо

Comment: Стоит добавить больше контекста. Например, откуда берется rand, что в этой переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо выдать права на запуск EXE-файлу.

Либо запускать, например, так:

```
exec(`start C:/upd/${rand}.exe`,  /* ... */ );
```